# Do you have to instantiate [RunInstaller(true)]-classes?

Tags: c#, installation

I found this code sample on [MSDN website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventloginstaller%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). My question is regarding the last line where they instantiate the class in the main method. But is that necessary? According to the documentation on [Installutil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50614e95.aspx):

> Installutil.exe uses reflection to inspect the specified assemblies
>   and to find all Installer types that have the
>   System.ComponentModel.RunInstallerAttribute attribute set to true. The
>   tool then executes either the Installer.Install or the
>   Installer.Uninstall method on each instance of the Installer type.

So does it mean that the main method and the instantiation of the MyEventLogInstaller-class is not necessarty?

```
using System;
using System.Configuration.Install;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ComponentModel;

[RunInstaller(true)]
public class MyEventLogInstaller: Installer
{
    private EventLogInstaller myEventLogInstaller;

    public MyEventLogInstaller() 
    {
        // Create an instance of an EventLogInstaller.
        myEventLogInstaller = new EventLogInstaller();

        // Set the source name of the event log.
        myEventLogInstaller.Source = "NewLogSource";

        // Set the event log that the source writes entries to.
        myEventLogInstaller.Log = "MyNewLog";

        // Add myEventLogInstaller to the Installer collection.
        Installers.Add(myEventLogInstaller);   
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        MyEventLogInstaller myInstaller = new MyEventLogInstaller();
    }
}
```